# How to get a JsonProcessingException using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Might be a strange question but indeed I would like to achieve a a bit more coverage on my tests and although I coded against a `JsonProcessingException` I can't create a payload that generates this exception, maybe because Jackson is quite smart and converts everything to a string, and even for bad strings it goes around the JSON specs. My problem is that Jackson is quite good :)

I basically want a payload that when I run this, it break with `JsonProcessingException`:

```
String jsonPayload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
```

I've tried some like:

```
HashMap<String, String> invalidJSONPayload= new HashMap<>();

invalidJSONPayload.put("021",021);
invalidJSONPayload.put("---",021);
invalidJSONPayload.put("~",021);
```

I'm not fussed with the type, so feel free to suggest another one. An empty object for example, throws `JsonMappingException` and I already catch that one as well.

Comment: Well, you can mock an `ObjectMapper` and have it throw that exception since `ObjectMapper` is not final

Comment: Wouldn't that be mocking the test itself, I would like to reproduce a scenario that can in fact happen in the context of the running application. Maybe one does not exists? If so, Why the exception? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, I thought you wanted to test the behaviour of your code in the event that this exception was raised, which is why I suggested this

Comment: I guess it makes sense, and if no other suggestions come up I might as well do that. I just figured there should be a way to produce that exception with some sort of random object that would not parse correctly to JSON. Damn Jackson and it's intelligent parsing.

Comment: You could try giving it some XML... :-)

Answer (score 27):

Building off of Liam's answer, mocking the `toString()` method with a cycle also causes Jackson to break.

```
@Test
public void forceJsonParseException() {
    try {
        Object mockItem = mock(Object.class);
        when(mockItem.toString()).thenReturn(mockItem.getClass().getName());
        new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mockItem);
        fail("did not throw JsonProcessingException");
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        //pass
    }
}
```

EDIT: It's way easier than that. A Mockito mock will always throw it. o.o;;

Comment: Worked for me. Since the mocked item isn't serializable, the exception is throw if you use this mocked item as a parameter of your tested method. You don't need the `when` clause btw.

Answer (score 26):

I wanted to do the same thing, and eventually accomplished it by using the Mockito "spy" function, which wraps a real object with a mock object. All calls to the mock object get forwarded to the real object, except those you are trying to mock. For example:

```
ObjectMapper om = Mockito.spy(new ObjectMapper());
Mockito.when( om.writeValueAsString(ErrorObject.class)).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("") {});
```

All usages of `om` will be handled by the underlying ObjectMapper instance until an instance of `ErrorObject` gets passed in, at which point the `JsonProcessingException` will be thrown.

The new`JsonProcessingException` is created as an anonymous class, as it is a protected class and only a sub-class can be instantiated.

Comment: Assuming the payload object has public getter and setter methods, you could simply use spy on the payload object and then have one of the getters return null.

Payload payloadSpy = Mockito.spy(payload);        Mockito.doReturn(null).when(payloadSpy).getField();
String jsonPayload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payloadSpy);

Comment: this will throw `Checked exception is invalid for this method!` and does not work

Comment: JsonProcessingException constructor has protect access modifier. So, cannot create by calling `new JsonProcessingException("")`

Answer (score 19):

You could use something like this:

```java
private static class ClassThatJacksonCannotSerialize {
    private final ClassThatJacksonCannotSerialize self = this;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return self.getClass().getName();
   }
}
```

Which results in a `JsonProcessingException` with message `Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: ClassThatJacksonCannotSerialize["self"])`

Comment: With 2.9, I couldn't replicate with the `toString` override, I had to do this:
```private static class WillNotSerialize {
    public WillNotSerialize getSelf() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

following on @Mike.Mathieson answer

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JacksonTest {

    @Test(expected = JsonProcessingException.class)
    // actually throws an InvalidDefinitionException (which extends JsonProcessingException)
    public void encodeThrowsException() throws JsonProcessingException {
        new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Object());
    }
}
```

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException.html

note that this test won't work if the ObjectMapper have been configured to disable `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`, e.g.

```
new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
    .writeValueAsString(new Object());
```

Answer (score 16):

For me, if a class has no `public` fields/methods, `writeValueAsString` will throw a `JsonMappingException` (`no serializer found for class...`)

```java
private static class ClassThatJacksonCannotSerialize {}

private void forceProcessingException() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
    } 
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Used this in my test to cover the throw clause :+1:

Answer (score 14):

You can get a JsonProcessingException if mapping two fields to the same property.

```
class InvalidObject {
    @JsonProperty("s")
    private String x = "value1";
    
    @JsonProperty("s")
    private String y = "value2";
}
```

Exception message is "Multiple fields representing property "s":..."

Comment: This is super simple solution and should be marked as answer. Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Throw exception in getter to simulate JsonProcessingException.

```
public static class TestData {
    public String getEx() throws JsonProcessingException { throw new JsonParseException(null, "test"); }
}

ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new TestData());
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add some explanation to the code to further guide OP.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to mock using `mock(ObjectMapper.class)` will invariably result in *Checked exception is invalid for this method!* as it is not possible to throw checked exception (`JsonProcessingException` extends `IOException`). Creating a self referencing value object like other answers suggested could be too convoluted for many cases and looks like a hack.

The easiest way I found is to extend `ObjectMapper` and then use that in your test method. You should pass the subclass to SUT

```
@Test
public void buildJsonSwallowsJsonProcessingException() {

    class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
        @Override
        public String writeValueAsString(Object value)
                throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException {
            throw new com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException("Forced error") {};
        }
    }

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new MyObjectMapper();

    SUTBean sutbean = new SUTBean(objectMapper);

    sutbean.testMethod();

    assertTrue(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this in Jackson Github issue; but it solved my problem and I am able to throw the JsonProcessingException.

```
 @Test
public void forceJsonParseException() {
try {
    Object mockItem = mock(Object.class);
    when(mockItem.toString()).thenReturn(mockItem.getClass().getName());
    new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mockItem);
    fail("did not throw JsonProcessingException");
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    //pass
}
}
```

Now how I used this in my code

Need to test this method

```
public String geResponse(MyObject myObject) {

try {
  return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
  log.error("Service response JsonParsing error {} ", e.getMessage());
  return "Validation Service response JsonParsing error {} "+ e.getMessage();
 }
}
```

This how I test the JsonProcessingException

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void testGetValidationResponseNegative() {
    MyObject mockItem = mock(MyObject.class);
    when(mockItem.toString()).thenReturn(mockItem.getClass().getName());
    String vr = geResponse(mockItem);
    assertTrue(!vr.isEmpty());
}
```

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

i was land on this question because i had the same target of the questioner:

> Might be a strange question but indeed I would like to achieve a a bit
> more coverage on my tests

IMHO Mockito solution it's more elegant and not introduce misunderstanding but I challenged a colleague to find another solution and he did. This is the solution:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Object To Json KO")
void objectToJsonKOTest() {
    KafkaMessageDTO o = new KafkaMessageDTO() {
        @Override
        public String getAuthCode() {
            int a = 2/0;
            return super.getAuthCode();
        }
    };

    String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
    Assertions.assertTrue(s.isEmpty());
}
```

This is trash, high level trash :) , but it works and I wanted to share it with you as an alternative to mock

ByeBye

Comment: That works for me. Mocking the ObjectMapper is a bad idea because I want to test the real ObjectMapper that is instantiated, and that's what this code does. However shouldn't it throw an excpetion instead of returning empty ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this value, it shall break, it broke for me::

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStringValue ="{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}";        
try {
            MyCustomClass classObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStringValue, MyCustomClass.class);
} catch(JsonProcessingException ex) {
//LOGGER / SYSOUT here
}
```

ERROR::JsonProcessingException / JsonParseException
Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
It really worked for me.. cheers..

Comment: This does not throw an error with jackson 2.14.3

Answer (score 0):

You can get `JsonProcessingException` via below code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class SomePOJOClass 
{
    // Lets assume there are your fields here.
}
// ...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objectNode = new ObjectNode();
objectNode.put("unknown-field-in-the-class", "and-its-value");
SomePOJOClass somePOJOClass = objectMapper.treeToValue(objectNode, SomePOJOClass .class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. Let's imagine you have:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass {
   @JsonProperty("field") Object myField;

   public String toJson() {
       try {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
       }
       catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
           throw new IllegalStateException(jpe);
       }
   }
}
```

You can add the following test to your suite to cover the catch block:

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void triggerJsonProcessingException() {
    class SelfRefrencing extends MyClass {
        @JsonProperty("self") SelfRefrencing self = this;
    }
    new SelfRefrencing(new MyClass()).toJson();
}
```