# How to write unit test for ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(object) which returns IOException

Tags: java, objectmapper

I am writing unit tests for `ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object)`.
I have a catch block which catches IOException. 
I need to unit test this catch block.

I need to know in which case, `IOException` is returned by `ObjectMapper`.

To throw JsonProcessingException, I already found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716020/how-to-get-a-jsonprocessingexception-using-jackson)

But I didn't find any scenarios which throws IOException.

```
 protected void logJsonForMetrics(final Logger logger,
                                     final Object object)
    {
        try
        {
            final String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
            logger.info(jsonString);
        }
        catch (final JsonProcessingException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to create a json object" + e);
        }
        catch (final IOExcepton e)
        {
            LOGGER.error("Error while logging metric " + e);
        }
    }
```

I want a scenario which returns IOException.

Answer (score 0):

This `writeValueAsString()` will most likely not throw an `IOException` because it use internally a `StringWriter` to write the value. From the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)):

> [...] Functionally equivalent to calling `writeValue(Writer,Object)` with `StringWriter` and constructing String [...]

If you want to check for `IOException`s you need to use the `writeValue()` method instead and provide a `Writer` object, which will throw the `IOException`.

Keep in mind that the `IOException` "throws" statement has been removed from `writeValueAsString()` as of version 2.1 (most likely because this exception isn't thrown there anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Note: prior to jackson-databind version 2.1, `writeValueAsString()` methods throws clause included IOException; 2.1 removed it.